# Grafana Monitoring Active DB Sessions - Dynamically

Tags: database, session, grafana

I've been thinking about how to monitor the active oracle sessions on the V$session view. 
The things i'd like to do are:

1. Graph (through a simple grafana graph panel) the sum of all active sessions every 5 minutes. I'm already working on a Perl script to do this.
2. Extract one or more "owners" of the highest number of active sessions on each poll and visualize them as a popup on the graph or in some other way.

I just want to know who is causing the high amount of sessions on the db.

Is it possible to do this? I hope so :D

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How many users do you have?  If it's less than say 1000 my suggestion would be to have your script report the number of active sessions for each user separately, that way you can easily visualize not only the total active sessions but also the active sessions for each user.

Comment: Hi AussieDan, thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes i could take that road but i'd like to use a more "flexible" approach. The users are about 600 but my idea is to extract each time only the ones having more than a predefined number of active sessions.  It would be great to have them dynamically displayed. Thanks though.